# How to comment out a particular line using ansible

Tags: regex, ansible

I have to comment out a line **clear_me** from the config file for now as part of workaround. The example file looks like this as below . I don't want to add a comment before def clear_me

```
def clear_me
    FactValue.where("user_id = #{id}").delete_all
  end

  def clear_userdata
    return unless .....  
    clear_me
    clear_reports
  end
```

## when I do this :

```
- name: Comment out 
  replace:
          path: <>
          regexp: 'clear_me'
          replace: '#clear_me'
          backup: yes
```

I see two replacements are made ie, the clear_me before my def is also commented out . What am I missing?? :

```
o/p:
changed: [localhost] => {"backup_file": "user.27018.2018-12-04@21:29:58~", "changed": true, "msg": "2 replacements made"

cat <file_name? | grep clear_me
  def **#clear_me**
    **#clear_me**
```

I only need to comment out the stand alone string clear_me  and not one that is in with def

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex pattern in the question will match any number of word `clear_me` in the file. Changing the regex pattern to the below, will change only the line you actually intend to.

The regex pattern means, match a line starting the any number of space and has clear_me

```
regex='^ +clear_me$'
```

or, you could also use the below regex and replace

```
regexp='^( +clear_me$)'
replace='#\1'
```